# Dr Memory Unitialized Read Error Disagrees With Dissasembly

Tags: c, dr-memory

I have a simple loop whose purpose is to split a line of a (very simple) csv into columns. The relevant section of the foor loop is as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i< csvRowReader->_currentRowTextLength; i++)
{
    char character = csvRowReader->_currentRowText[i];

    if (character == ',') { ... }
    ...
}
```

Dr Memory reports the following uninitialized read:

```
Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading register eax
         CsvRowReader_MoveNext
             c:\users\holli\projects\transporter\source\csv\csvrowreader.c(116):
         ...
```

Now in an attempt to diagnose what was going on viewed the disassembly for that line of code:

```
   116:         if (character == ',')
00D4A40F  movsx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-35h]  
00D4A413  cmp         eax,2Ch  
00D4A416  jne         CsvRowReader_MoveNext+1F5h (0D4A545h)
```

At `00D4A413` the register `EAX` has a value of `EAX = 0000006E`. Which is `'n'`:

```
(char)(0x0000006E)
110 'n'
```

So as far as I can tell `eax` is initialized with a value in this case `'n'`. I am at my wits end trying to figure out what is causing this error, any any help be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Complete speculation: is the "character" variable being optimised away by the compiler? So the eax contents are directly csvRowReader->_currentRowText[i]? In which case the question is whether that location was properly initalised, which we cannot tell from this snippet.

Comment: @djna I had thought about that but wouldn't the disassembly be the same as the compiled code (if both were run/built in in Debug mode)?

Comment: @djna Also I have disabled all optimisation related settings in my project as per (http://drmemory.org/docs/page_prep.html)

Comment: It's clear from the assembly that the character is **not** being optimised away. @HennyH this looks like a bug in your memory tool, eax is clearly being set before the comparison.